# Best .Net 4.0 web hosting

Tags: .net, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

After dealing with problematic web hosting company, I have to move to a new one. Which do you think is the best for .Net?

TY

Comment: Off topic for here. Try on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking to host your asp.net website, you always have to consider a host that particularly focuses on ASP.NET and microsoft technology only. There are lots of hosts out there which appears to be "all-rounder" (i.e. supports everything, ranging from Linux, Free BSD, ASP.NET, PHP or anything you can name). These kind of hosts are not recommended because you have to look only for a host that truly knowledge-able and have focus on ASP.NET only

In this case, I would recommend you to consider [asphostcentral.com](http://www.asphostcentral.com/default.aspx) as this host only focuses in ASP.NET and Windows hosting. Hope this helps!